# Lotus Note installation on Linux Mint 14?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, software-installation, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to install IBM Lotus Note 8.5.3 on Linux Mint 14 using terminal. Problem is that it's not installing and showing following error

```
sudo apt-get install ibm-lotus-notes-8.5.3.i586.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ibm-lotus-notes-8.5.3.i586.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ibm-lotus-notes-8.5.3.i586.deb'
```

I've install Lotus Note 8.5.3 on Ubuntu 12.04, without any problem. How can I solve this problem now on Linux Mint 14?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `dpkg -i` to install a .deb file that you have local.

```
$ dpkg -i ibm-lotus-notes-8.5.3.i586.deb
```

From the `dpkg` man page:

```
Usage: dpkg [<option> ...] <command>

Commands:
  -i|--install       <.deb file name> ... | -R|--recursive <directory> ...
```

#### References

- [dpkg man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html)